# Getting a Schengen visa as an unregistered freelancer from India

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, hungary, freelance

I am travelling to Hungary for an all expenses paid coding competition I have been invited to by a very well known company. I need to apply for a tourist visa.

I am currently residing in India and quit my job a few months back. I am freelancing now and have a decent income. Unfortunately I haven't registered myself as a business yet. Is this going to be a problem?

I have the following documents:

- Return flight tickets
- Accommodation confirmation
- Invitation letter from the company stating the purpose and sponsorship on their letterhead
- 6 months bank statements showing income and consistent savings
- Travel insurance covering 50k USD
- 3 years of Tax Returns

Is there any risk of my visa getting rejected?

Comment: Can you demonstrate the source of all of the deposits into your bank account? They will be looking for this information.

Comment: I can show invoices @MichaelHampton

Comment: @MichaelHampton. I can get a letter from my client saying I was freelancing with them

Comment: Are you sure that what you need is a tourist visa? "invited to by a very well known company" does not sound like "tourism" to me. Please note that I do not claim anything, only that maybe you want to ensure that point (probably asking such company should be enough).

Answer (score 4):

There are a few issues:

1. The purpose of your trip is not tourism, so right there your application is likely to get rejected. You should mark "OTHER" and list the actual reason you are going, something like "Professional Conference" or similar.
2. You are missing the Schengen Medical Insurance - which covers healthcare and repatriation (its not the same thing as travel insurance). The minimum coverage is 30,000 EUR.
3. Bank statements should show income *and expenditures* that demonstrate a lifestyle commensurate with your social and economical status, and the fact that you are able to support yourself for the purposes of the trip and not be a burden on state resources.
4. Finally and perhaps most importantly, they are also looking for a reason for you to come back (which the sponsor cannot provide), thus you have to show compelling ties to your home land. This is where you have the highest burden of proof as without a job to return to, there is nothing stopping you from overstaying your visa.